# Elasticsearch-rails completion suggester, map data, create indexes, suggest method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I am using `elasticsearch-model` and `elasticsearch-rails` gems.

In my Profile model I have

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 3 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false'  do
      indexes :profile_type, analyzer: 'keyword'
      indexes :profile do |p|
        indexes :name, type: 'multi_field' do
          indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball'
          indexes :tokenized, analyzer: 'keyword'
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

I tried adding `suggest` field

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 3 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false'  do
      indexes :profile_type, analyzer: 'keyword'
      indexes :suggest, type: 'suggest' # not sure about this
      # do not really know how to index this field
      indexes :profile do |p|
        indexes :name, type: 'multi_field' do
          indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball'
          indexes :tokenized, analyzer: 'keyword'
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

I am trying to make suggest on `profile.name` , I have added `as_indexed_json`

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
    suggest= {
     suggest: {
      :input => profile.name,
      :output => profile.name,
      :payload => {
        name: profile.name
      }
     }
    }
    self.as_json(
      :only => [:profile_type, :slug],
      :include => {
        :profile => {}
      }
    ).merge(suggest)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to map data, using `elasticsearch-rails` gem

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 3 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false'  do
      indexes :profile_type, analyzer: 'keyword'
      indexes :suggest, type: 'completion', index_analyzer: 'simple', search_analyzer: 'simple', payloads: true
      # will do the trick
      indexes :profile do |p|
        indexes :name, type: 'multi_field' do
          indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball'
          indexes :tokenized, analyzer: 'keyword'
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

Then to create indexes

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
    suggest= {
     suggest: {
      :input => profile.name,
      :output => profile.name,
      :payload => {
        name: profile.name
      }
     }
    }
    self.as_json(
      :only => [:profile_type, :slug],
      :include => {
        :profile => {}
      }
    ).merge(suggest)
end
```

Then do not use `search` method, instead use `suggest` method

```
  def self.suggest query
    __elasticsearch__.client.suggest(:index => index_name, :body => {
      :suggestions => {
        :text => query,
        :completion => {
          :field => 'suggest',
          :size => 20
        }
      }
    })
  end
```

This way you get `complete suggestion`